# Read the values from a csv file and identify the unique names

Tags: java, arrays, csv, input, talend

I am using talend function and component to read and extract the values from a csv file and find the unique values under a specific column A.

csv file contains:
[image: csv]

In this case ,i want to read the NAME column which serves as the header and identify only the unique names(Tom,Jason,Roy,Bianca) from that name category and store it in a array and i can use them to check if the incoming   name from the new file exists or matches the name extracted from the csv file above.

Job Design:

- tfilelist->tjava

**tJava**:

```
  int n = 600;  
  int i=0;
  String line="";
  int linenumber=0;
  int index=0;
       
 try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))))
 { 
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && linenumber< n )  
 {
    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    System.out.println("Columns=>" + tokens[0]);
  }
 }
```

context.name will be the global variable that contains all the unique names
Is there any other better efficient way of handling the csv file and extracting only unique names from the column A and store it in a list/array where we can validate against it?

Appreciate your inputs.Thanks

I guess the best option would be to use br.readLine() and store the values by using split function(",") and store it in a hashset.
Then hashset.contains to validate if that incoming names in the new file matches with the stored hashset value or not and correspondingly decide the flow of data.

I just now need to find the UNIQUE entries under column A and i dont want the header to be displayed in my output.

OUTPUT:
Columns NAME
Columns Tom
Columns Jason
Columns Tom
Columns Roy
Columns Bianca

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be:

1. Create 2 HashSet, 'unique' and 'duplicate'.
2. for each line, split it with a '.' being the delimiter and index the first element (being the name on that row)
3. if duplicate.contains(name) == true, then continue to next name
4. if unique.contains(name) == true, then unique.remove(name), duplicate.add(name),
   else unique.add(name)
5. at the end, the unqiue hashset contains all the unique names.

Comment: `Set` - *A collection that contains no duplicate elements.*